# True/False: Is it possible that the following limits all hold true?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

> For  $g:\ \Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$, it is possible that $$\lim\limits_{x\to -3}\frac{g(x)-g(-3)}{x-(-3)}=5$$ with $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}g\left(-3+\frac{1}{n}\right)=7$, and
>   $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}g\left(-3+\frac{\pi}{n^2}\right)=5$.

Okay, so I know the last two limits are essentially the same thing, so the answer must be false. But how do I prove that using the definition of a limit?

Comment: Can you please write it out in LaTeX, cause I can't read the picture: it's too small. Also, are you asking if all of these conditions are true for a single $g$ or for a single $g$?

Comment: In order for $g$ to be differentiable at $-3$, it must be continuous at $-3$...

Comment: The last two limits show it's not continuous.

Comment: Reminds me of $\sin\frac{1}{x}$. Btw, what is the book are you reading, @sfgiantsfan19 ?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help everyone! Also @AlexeyBurdin the book is Elementary Analysis: The Theory of Calculus 2nd Ed. by Ross

Comment: In response to a system flag (caused by a large number of comments) I purged the thread quite a bit. The exchange was about a misundertanding a single user had, and are not entirely relevant to the question at hand. Some quality comments became collateral damage - I apologize for that. If you still need to review the deleted comments, please @-ping me or flag another moderator to undelete the comments.

Comment: No worries @JyrkiLahtonen I had read them before they were deleted, and my question got answered from another comment as well. Thanks again for everyone's help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\lim_{x \to -3}\dfrac{g(x)-g(-3)}{x-(-3)} = 5$, we have
$$\lim_{x \to -3} \left(g(x) - g(-3)\right) = 5\cdot \lim_{x \to -3} \left(x-(-3)\right) \implies \lim_{x \to -3}g(x) = g(-3)$$
However, $\lim_{n \to \infty} g\left(-3+\dfrac1n\right) = 7$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} g\left(-3+\dfrac{\pi}{n^2}\right) = 5$, contradicting the fact that $\lim_{x \to -3}g(x) = g(-3)$.

Comment: "$\lim\limits_{x \to -3} \left(g(x) - g(-3)\right)=\dots$" under an assumption that this limit exists. How do I prove the existence?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin If $\lim_x f(x)$ and $\lim_x g(x)$ exists, then so does  $\lim_x f(x)g(x)$.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin He's reached a contradiction by assuming (all) the limits exist. Therefore that cannot be the case (some limit must not exist or not have the values indicated).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}f(x) = L$ if and only if, for every sequence $\left \{p_n \right \}$ such that

- $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}p_n=a$
- $p_n \neq a$ for all $n$

Then $$\lim_{n \to \infty}f(p_n)=L$$

Comment: We don't need sequences for this: this is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: $g(-3+{1 \over n})$ is a sequence